# Android - Fragments and multi-page forms

Tags: android

So I have an `FragmentActivity`that contains 3 tabs, one tab is essentially a mullti-page(view) form, like so:

```
FragmentActivity    

tab 1 -> Fragment
tab 2(MultiPage) -> Fragment Page 1 (onClick for Next button) -> Fragment Page 2 -> Fragment Page n
tab 3 -> Fragment
```

What would be the best way to handle this? Is it possible to keep in my current tab selection while filling out the form and going thru the pages? Is this a bad practice?

Comment: For Multipage fragment using ViewFlipper is the best way I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any UI pattern, the best practice implementation is what the pattern was designed for. This is evidentiary in lots of examples starting from days of Web and forms the basis of HTML Semantics

If you don't implement your solution on the same line, the pattern was designed for, your codes may break in future in case it's ran on a custom hardware or OS. There could be some other examples too.

Now, what you're talking about is a wizard for multi page form and I think designing a set of activities is best since it aligns with Android navigation fundamental of back button as well

thoughts are welcome :)